# NODEJS - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, node.js, steam

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near \'desc) VALUES (\'Haunted Candleer\',
>   \'fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVj\' at line 1',
>
> .
>
> { Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES ('Haunted Candleer', 'fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVj' at line 1

.

> 'INSERT INTO shop (name, img, desc) VALUES (\'Haunted Candleer\', \'fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZULUrsm1j-9xgEDe1VBDEjdszFNjMTvA82PCe4El98m2pxUyzFu31l-ZrO0aGA2cVCUB_QJDKRqpF68USYx6Zc7A4bmp71WLQnq59GTZrEycIYbjr3FIXk\', \'123123\') '

Работаю с NodeJS, Mysql, steam

Использую данные из инвентаря Steam

```
  name: 'Haunted Candleer',
  type: 'Level 71 Costume Piece',
```

Выдает ошибки выше (указаны выше)

```
manager.loadUserInventory('76561198853657017',440, 2, true, (err, inventory) => {
    var sql1 = "INSERT INTO shop (name, desc) VALUES ? ";
    var type = inventory[0].type;
    var name = inventory[0].name;
    var values = [
        [name, type]
    ];
    con.query(sql1, [values], function (err, result3) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Жду help

Comment: Возможно `[values]` должно быть `values`, но вообще это какая-то муть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я делал так:

```
var sql1 = "INSERT INTO shop set ?";
var values = { type: inventory[0].type, name: inventory[0].name };
con.query(sql1, [values], function (err, result3) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Comment: Если помогло, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него. И ещё соседний проверь пожалуйста - удалить мне его или оставить?

Comment: оставь, мало ли кому-то поможет

Comment: @ArtemPresnyakof, так я тот наугад написал - я предполагаю, что та версия может работать, но не проверял. У меня в старом коде эта, а проверять не на чем.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно такое сработает (если нет, удалю ответ):

```
var sql1 = "INSERT INTO shop (name, desc) VALUES (?, ?) ";
var values = [inventory[0].name, inventory[0].type];
con.query(sql1, values, function (err, result3) {
    console.log(err);
});
```